# Chat with your DB: How to get AI to follow your rules?

Tags: python, large-language-models, training-datasets, natural-language-understanding

**Context/Background:** I have a single table in MySQL with info on 'members', including things like location, favourite types of music, favourite camping spots, etc.

**Required Behaviour:** I need the system to:

Have the AI 'match' people based on rules. Rules are, for example: Only match people in the same age-range who like the same music and enjoy outdoor festivals.

Allow me to ask questions of the DB, such as "how many rock lovers between 21 and 30 went to the burning man festival?"

**Attempts:** My latest efforts were using the Chainlit library for Python, trying various LLMs.

**Actual Behaviour:** It would appear to work at first, but would immediately fail to follow the most basic 'rules'. I would get the bot to admit it didn't follow the rule and yet it would continue to disobey.

I know this is of course already being done, I just can't get anyone (after spending hundreds on developers) who knows how to do this.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions for a solution.

**Chainlit Code:**

chainlit_app.py

```
    import os

from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain import SQLDatabase, SQLDatabaseChain
from prompting import SQLITE_PROMPT
import tiktoken
from langchain.text_splitter import 
RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFDirectoryLoader
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.docstore.document import Document
from langchain import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.llms import OpenAI

tokenizer = tiktoken.get_encoding("cl100k_base")

def tiktoken_len(text):
    tokens = tokenizer.encode(text, disallowed_special=())
    return len(tokens)


os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = "APIKEY"


docsearch = ""

if os.path.exists("./store/index.faiss"):
    docsearch = FAISS.load_local("./store", OpenAIEmbeddings())
else:
    print("does't exist")
    loader = PyPDFDirectoryLoader("./traindata")
    text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(
        separator="\n", chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200, 
length_function=len
    )
    texts = loader.load_and_split(text_splitter)
    docsearch = FAISS.from_documents(texts, OpenAIEmbeddings())
    local_url = "./store"
    docsearch.save_local(local_url)

# @cl.on_message
# async def main(message):
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri("sqlite:///members_full.db", 
view_support=True)                   
llm = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-4")    
agent = SQLDatabaseChain(llm=llm, database=db, verbose=False)
agent.llm_chain.prompt = SQLITE_PROMPT

while 1:
    message = input("Ask away! : ")

    res = docsearch.similarity_search(message)
    chain = load_qa_chain(OpenAI(temperature=0), 
chain_type="stuff")
    completion = chain.run(input_documents=res, question=message)
    if "I don't know" in completion or "not mentioned" in 
completion or "not provided" in completion:
        res_agent = agent(message)
        print(res_agent['result'])
    else:
        print(completion)



from rule_system import get_rule_based_response

def get_response(user_query):
    rule_response = get_rule_based_response(user_query)
    if rule_response:
        return rule_response

    ai_response = get_ai_response(user_query)
    return ai_response
```

prompting.py

```
    from langchain.prompts.prompt import PromptTemplate
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory

settings = {
    "temperature": 2,
    "max_tokens": 500
  
}

# Define custom instructions
custom_instructions = "Remember, we need to strictly follow the 

rules in the train1.pdf regarding location, favorite music, 
favorite camping sites, etc.
    

table_additional_info = """\n members_free Table Value Mapping
gender  : 0 means Female , 1 means Male

there is no field named first_name.  do not query for first_name in 
the db or query for any 'name' variable.
never display a person's name.

"""

PROMPT_SUFFIX = """Only use the following tables:

{table_info}



""" + table_additional_info +"""

Question: {input}"""

_sqlite_prompt = """You are a helpful and friendly SQLite expert         
and always do the SQL queries necessary. Given an input question, 

first create a syntactically correct SQLite query to run, then look 
at the results of the query and return the answer to the input 
question.

Unless the user specifies in the question a specific number of 
examples to obtain, query for at most {top_k} results using the 
LIMIT clause as per SQLite. You can order the results to return the 
most informative data in the database.
Never query for all columns from a table. You must query only the 
columns that are needed to answer the question. Wrap each column 
name in double quotes (") to denote them as delimited identifiers.
Pay attention to use only the column names you can see in the 
tables below. Be careful to not query for columns that do not 
exist. Also, pay attention to which column is in which table.
Pay attention to use date('now') function to get the current date, 
if the question involves "today".
You never create or invent answers.  When you are asked for 
'matches' or to 'match someone' you will always follow the rules 
in the train1.pdf precisely.  You will not tell me to run a query 
or check the data for myself, you will run the 
required query to respond to my questions.

Before generating a response, ensure you are adhering strictly to 
the guidelines set forth in our training documentation. 
This is crucial for providing accurate and reliable answers. The 
rules in "train1.pdf" are especially critical 
and must be followed at all times. Non-compliance with these rules 
will lead to suboptimal performance and may not 
meet the user's expectations. Always prioritize these guidelines in 
every interaction.

Use the following format:

Question: Question here
SQLQuery: SQL Query to run
SQLResult: Result of the SQLQuery
Answer: Final answer here


Please always follow the rules outlined in the train1.pdf.  This is 
absolutely essential to this app working.

You will not invent any answers or falsify data.
You will do all the SQL queries when asked to do a match or 
retrieve data from the database or training documents.
When you provide matches, you will include your reasoning in why 
you think the matches are a good fit for the target user.
When asked to match a target user to an event in the db, you will 
start with the most recent entries in the db by referencing the 
'date' field in the db.




"""

SQLITE_PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["input", "table_info", "top_k"],
    template=_sqlite_prompt + PROMPT_SUFFIX,
)
```

rule_system.py

```
rule_based_answers = {
"What rules do I need to follow as the Ai?"; "The rules in the 
train1.pdf",
"What is the company's address?": "123 Main St, Sample City, 
Country",
"How can I contact support?": "Please email support@example.com.",
# ... add more predefined answers
}

def get_rule_based_response(query):
return rule_based_answers.get(query)
```

I can't include the DB or the Training guide, but that shouldn't matter - it often provides accurate results on direct queries to the DB, just not following the Rules when asked to do a 'match'.

If I can provide anything further that might help, please let me know.

Comment: I am 100% open to a different solution than this, so no matter what the platform - if you have any suggestions on how to accomplish the ultimate goal here (to force AI to follow your 'rules' when chatting with a DB), I would really appreciate hearing them.